# Installing Ios apps from Itunes Using AppleScript

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, applescript, itunes

I am using Apple Script to search apps in iTunes, but after getting search results i need to extract the information about search results and then click on Get button to download ipa into my Mac.

```
tell application "iTunes"
    open location "itms://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?WOURLEncoding=ISO8859_1&lang=1&output=lm&country=US&media=software&term=box"
end tell
```